# Adding pdf document to Solr in Java

Tags: java, pdf, solr, solrj

I can add field like this in `Java`, but I want to add pdf document to `Solr` with SolrJ in `Java`, how can I add a pdf file?

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();

doc.addField("cat", "lalal");
doc.addField("id", "1");

server.add(doc);
server.commit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr uses Apache Tika to process binary files.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler and http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ContentStreamUpdateRequestExample for a SolrJ example.

Comment: i did this, but i get compile exception in there.
     up.addFile(new File(fileName));

Comment: Then you didn't do it right. Are you using the version of Solr indicated? Are you missing dependencies?

Comment: exactly . version apache solr 4.0 . Which dependencies?

Comment: So, what is the actual compilation exception you are getting?

Comment: method addFile in class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.ContentStreamUpdateRequest cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.io.File,java.lang.String
  found: java.io.File
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: So, did you check the javadoc of the ContentStreamUpdateRequest of the version you are using? It looks like the signature of the method has changed.

Comment: yes, i checked, didn't change anything                               

 public void addFile(File file, String contentType) throws IOException {
        //compiled code
        throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
    }

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have to specify the content type now as well on that method. You can either do that, or I suppose you could try to use the `addContentStream` method and the `ContentStreamBase.FileStream` class.

Comment: thank you , it work , thankssss:) if , i don't disturb you , can you answer a question too ?